# Linux Mint Debian: Apparently benign error message with aptitude

Tags: aptitude, d-bus

When I use aptitude or apt-get at the command line to update/install or upgrade (sudo aptitude update/sudo aptitude install) I get the following error message

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

Everything appears to install and work fine, but I'd like to know what it means and how to stop it appearing please.